# Base 64 encoding with Scala or Java

Tags: java, scala, base64

I have tried :

```
val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val result = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(md.digest("user:pass".getBytes))
```

RESULT:

```
md: java.security.MessageDigest = SHA-1 Message Digest from SUN, <initialized>
result: String = smGaoVKd/cQkjm7b88GyorAUz20=
```

I also tried :

```
import java.net.URLEncoder
val result = URLEncoder.encode(user + ":" + pass, "UTF-8")
```

RESULT:

```
result: String = user%3Apass
```

Based on http://www.base64encode.org/
The value I am wanting for result should be "dXNlcjpwYXNz"

What is the site doing differently from these encodings?
Also, how might I mimic the site in Java/Scala?

Note, the specific application is for a header using Basic Authentication.

Comment: if you want to make your own i have some example, i made Base64 for scala [https://github.com/Try-Parser/Base64-encryption](https://github.com/Try-Parser/Base64-encryption)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get "user:pass" to "dXNlcjpwYXNz", you should be base64-encoding the UTF-8 encoded string, but not hashing.

Using the third-party Guava library, I can run

```
System.out.println(BaseEncoding.base64()
    .encode("user:pass".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));
```

and I get out

```
dXNlcjpwYXNz
```

as requested.  The other Base64 encoders should work similarly.

Comment: (Also, your second version with `URLEncoder` doesn't appear to actually do any hashing...or Base64 encoding...)

Comment: Thank you! That was perfect.  As for the second example, it was just to help rule out some of the answers that have been thrown at other similar questions.

Answer (score 97):

Since Java 8 there are handy utility classes directly in the standard library: [`Base64.Decoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) and [`Base64.Encoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html). There are also some static factory methods to construct instances of these classes which perform Base64 encoding/decoding for various flavors of Base64 in [`Base64`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class.

This is how to use the encoder:

```
import java.util.Base64
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString("user:pass".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

Comment: What's a suitable Java 7 alternative?

Answer (score 12):

Scala was asked:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

val (password, expected) = ("user:pass".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "dXNlcjpwYXNz")

assume(java.util.Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(password)==expected)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using [scalaj](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) (I was), you can simply do this:

```
import scalaj.http.Base64

Base64.encodeString(str)
```

Or

```
import scalaj.http.HttpConstants._

base64(str)
```